# MySQL: Select statement in a LIKE clause

Tags: mysql

I want to use `" like '%(selected result)%' "` phrase. 
Below code is mine

```
 where note like '%(SELECT ds_word.ds_en FROM ds_word
                     WHERE ds_co LIKE '%콜레라%' LIMIT 0 ,1)%'
```

But `'%~~~%'` use make an error, that is,

> "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '(SELECT code_co.code, code_co.disease_co, code_en.disease_en
>   FROM code_co LEFT' at line 44".

How can i use that expression?
Help me, please!

And, below answer outputs the result picture.
[image]
This is the captured picture on phpmyadmin.

Comment: your expression is breaking due to presence of single quotes in your search pattern. Escape the single quotes to overcome this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I think is, Since you are trying to use a value inside your LIKE statement, you will need to modify it to something like:

`where note like CONCAT('%',SELECT ds_word.ds_en FROM ds_word WHERE ds_co LIKE '%콜레라%' LIMIT 0 ,1, '%')`

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Neels, I followed your answer. but above picture outputs.

Comment: probably try this.. CONCAT('%',SELECT ds_word.ds_en FROM ds_word WHERE ds_co LIKE '%콜레라%' LIMIT 0 ,1, '%') may be the brackets aren't supposed to be there..

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE note LIKE
CONCAT ('%',(SELECT ds_word.ds_en FROM ds_word WHERE ds_co LIKE '%콜레라%' LIMIT 0 ,1), '%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `\` to escape the `'` which is the escape character

```
where note 
like '%(SELECT ds_word.ds_en FROM ds_word WHERE ds_co LIKE \'%콜레라%\' LIMIT 0 ,1)%';
```